# Portable getch() that works in JetBrains debugger console?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

There are many getch() around stackoverflow but none I have found work in the JetBrains debugger console. I know it is a weird not-a-real-tty but it would be nice if it worked a little bit (e.g. even if you had to press enter) throwing an exception.

Most of the 'portable' getch() suggestions are along the same lines, I just use the pipable one.

After installing Joe Esposito's library:

```
pip install py-getch
```

This works great, except in the debugger console:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from getch import getch, pause

key = getch()
print('You pressed:', key)
pause()
```

I know I can use the remote debug pydevd mechanism but that pretty intrusive just to debug the simple script.